# capitalize the first letter of each word in a sentence

Tags: javascript, arrays, capitalization

hey guy can anybody help me to fix my code so that it does the task shown in the text,

```
function tad(strg) {
    var char = strg.split('-')
    for (var i = 1; i < char.length; i++) {
        return char[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + char[i].slice(1)
    }
}

camelize("background-color") == 'backgroundColor'
camelize("list-style-image") == 'listStyleImage'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to replace all word combinations that have a hyphen in it to a camel cased word. You can use a regex with `String.replace` with a callback function that capitalizes all words after the hyphen.

```
function camelize (strg) {
  return strg.replace(/-(\w)/g, function (match) {
     return match[1].toUpperCase();
  });
} 

camelize("background-color");
// backgroundColor

camelize("z-index");
// zIndex

camelize("list-style-image");
// listStyleImage
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/YR3z6/)

Answer (score 1):

Change your function like bellow

```
function tad(strg) {
    var char = strg.split('-')
    for (var i = 1; i < char.length; i++) {
        char[i] = char[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + char[i].slice(1)
    }
    return char.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are returning before the loop completes its iterations. The best thing here would be to use `Array.prototype.reduce` like this

```
function tad(strg) {
    return strg.split('-').reduce(function(result, currentStr) {
        return result + currentStr.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + currentStr.slice(1);
    }, "");
}

console.log(tad("background-color") === "backgroundColor");
# true
console.log(tad("list-style-image") === "listStyleImage");
# true
```

Answer (score 0):

You `return` from the whole function in the first iteration of that loop. Instead, you want to do that for every part, and the join the parts together:

```
function camelize(string) {
    return string.split('-').map(function(part, i) {
        return i ? part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1) : part;
    }).join("");
}
// or
function camelize(string) {
    return string.split('-').reduce(function(m, part) {
        return m + part.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + part.slice(1);
    });
}
// or
function camelize(string) {
    var parts = string.split('-'),
        result = ""
    for (var i = 1; i < parts.length; i++) {
        result += parts[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + parts[i].slice(1)
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Your first function actually returns "BackgroundColor" for "background-color"

Comment: @yantrakaar: Oh, right, I didn't notice the OP wanted the *first word* differently. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should concatenate results in some variable, instead of returning in loop.

Secondly fo not forget to add first element of array, since your loop is starting from 1.

```
function camelize(strg) {
    var char = strg.split('-'), result = char[0]
    for (var i = 1; i < char.length; i++) {
         result += char[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + char[i].slice(1)
    }
    return result
}

alert(camelize("background-color"));
alert(camelize("list-style-image"));
```

Here is fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/C78T3/